# Random Forest algorithm in R

Tags: r, random-forest

How can I see the algorithm of a randomForest in R?

I have tried with:

```
library(randomForest)
radomForest
```

But the output I´ve got is:

```
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("randomForest")
<environment: namespace:randomForest>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't see much there, b/c `randomForest` is a S3 function and calls different functions depending on the class of the input you provide to the algorithm.
Typing `randomForest:::randomForest.default` gives you more information.

However, I assume that parts of the functions used therein are written in C or Fortran. To see all the code, there is a GitHub mirror of the cran package here: https://github.com/cran/randomForest

Note: `methods(randomForest)` returns the available methods of a S3 generic function. In this case:

```
methods(randomForest)
## [1] randomForest.default* randomForest.formula*
```